# Am getting the following TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: numpy, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have the error being displayed whilst trying to plot the graph...

I am sharing the code in the following link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nILxtGSSCmOKrcHg3-_SL0l2bsIwUM1p?usp=sharing

I think I'm missing 'tensor.cpu()' somewhere but I can't really pinpoint it.. Everything else works :/ Can anyone help please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing is that the result of `torch.sum(...)` is a tensor. Try to change it in the following way in the lines where you add to running_corrects/val_running_corrects: `torch.sum(...).item()` and then update code accordingly. There are probably other ways to do it but it should work. Here is very similar question by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72704295/14787618

Comment: Tried that and resulted in the following attribute error : ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7b87701d2384> in <module>()
     39 
     40     epoch_loss = running_loss/len(training_loader)
---> 41     epoch_acc = running_corrects.float()/len(training_loader)
     42     running_loss_history.append(epoch_loss)
     43     running_corrects_history.append(epoch_acc)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'float'

Comment: float() is not needed anymore, replace it with running_corrects/len(training_loader)

Comment: epoch : 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-74388a14dfbc> in <module>()
     48     val_running_corrects_history.append(val_epoch_acc)
     49     print('epoch :', (e+1))
---> 50     print('training loss: {:.4f}, acc {:.4f}'.format(epoch_loss, epoch_acc.item()))
     51     print('validation loss: {:.4f}, validation acc {:.4f}'.format(val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_acc.item()))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: The same for item() here, just remove it for both prints, like this:
    `print('training loss: {:.4f}, acc {:.4f}'.format(epoch_loss, epoch_acc))
    print('validation loss: {:.4f}, validation acc {:.4f}'.format(val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_acc))`

Comment: THANKS so much! @serhii Maksymenko