# How to solve RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I had done a model training on Densenet161 and I saved my model

```
torch.save(model_ft.state_dict(),'/content/drive/My Drive/Stanford40/densenet161.pth')
```

and follow by this

```
model = models.densenet161(pretrained=False,num_classes=11)
model_ft.classifier=nn.Linear(2208,11)


model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/drive/My Drive/Stanford40/densenet161.pth'))
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model=model.to(device)
```

Then, when I want to proceed to the model evaluation

```
test_tuple=datasets.ImageFolder('/content/drive/My Drive/Stanford40/body/valid',transform=data_transforms['valid'])
test_dataloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_tuple,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)

class_names=test_tuple.classes
i=0

length=dataset_sizes['valid']
y_true=torch.zeros([length,1])
y_pred=torch.zeros([length,1])

for inputs ,labels in test_dataloader:
  
  model_ft.eval()

  inputs=inputs.to(device)
  outputs=model_ft(inputs)

   
  y_true[i][0]=labels
   
  maxvlaues,indices = torch.max(outputs, 1)
  y_pred[i][0]=indices
  i=i+1
```

and I face the error as in the picture:
[image]

when I check whether my model was moved to the device with this code
`next(model.parameters()).is_cuda`
The result is True.

**How can I modify the code to get away from this error?**

My **model training part** can be found at [How to solve TypeError: can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699547/how-to-solve-typeerror-can-t-convert-cuda-tensor-to-numpy-use-tensor-cpu-to)

Answer (score 0):

You have moved `model` to the GPU, but not `model_ft`. The runtime error is at `outputs = model_ft(inputs)`. Could it be a case of mixed-up variable names?